# error: QApplication: No such file or directory - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: qt, qt-quick

**Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**

**Qt version:**

```
$ qmake -v
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

**.pro** file:

```
TEMPLATE += app
QT += core gui declarative
SOURCES += qtCppIntegration.cpp
```

**.cpp** file:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QUrl>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QQuickView view;
  view.setSource(QUrl("/home/...plesQtQuickQML/anchors.qml"));
  view.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

**error:**

```
$ make
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtDeclarative -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -o qtCppIntegration.o qtCppIntegration.cpp
qtCppIntegration.cpp:1:24: fatal error: QApplication: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [qtCppIntegration.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Your code gives me another error: QQuickView not declared. It happens because this class is available only in Qt5. IIRC, in Qt4 it is called QDeclarativeView.

About your problem: a you sure that you have reexecuted qmake before make?

Comment: @Kakadu Thanks, your QDeclarativeView comment helped w.r.t the other error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This did the trick:

`sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev`

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu 14.04 if you get the same error:

```
ABC$ make
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I. -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -o textpad.o textpad.cpp
textpad.cpp:1:24: fatal error: QApplication: No such file or directory
 #include <QApplication>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [textpad.o] Error 1
```

Try `qmake-qt4` and then `make`. Of course you can get all the QT4 libraries if its not present using:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
```